# Could I possibly be shown how to use a procedure to add data to 2 separate tables, then reference one of them in the other

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

**I am new to SQL Server - Please excuse any ignorance.**

I am creating a site, and database, for user information and interaction.

I have 2 main user tables, **tblSiteMember** and **tblSiteMemberDetail**.

tblSiteMember contains: **id**, **refKey**
tblSiteMemberDetail contains **id**, **userId**, **username**, **password** etc...

I want to link all the other tables to reference only tblSiteUser, while the tblSiteUserDetail will contain a reference back to tblSiteUser, and will store all its information.

The diagram below will illustrate:

[image: Illistration]

Unfortunately, due to my lack of knowledge in SQL, I do not know how to make a stored procedure (such as procAddMember) to add the user to **tblSiteMember**, then add their details to **tblSiteMemberDetail**, and also include a reference to **tblSiteMember** on **tblSiteMemberDetail**.

Would someone please be so kind as to show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "id" is an identity column in tblSiteMember, you'd do something like this in a single stored pro:

Declare @siteMemberID int

Insert Into tblSiteMember (_columns)
Values (_values)

Set @siteMemberID = @@Identity

Insert Into tblSiteMemberDetail (siteMemberID, _other columns)
Values (@siteMemberID, _other values)

This can all be wrapped in a single transaction of course.

Answer (score 3):

A single stored procedure wrapping all of these in a transaction is a fairly standard way of ensuring data consistency directly in the database.

It has the added bonus of being a single call to the database.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Could you possibly show me a way to do this? As I said, i also want to add the reference. I am fairly new to databasing.

Comment: @NewAmbition - I suggest asking a new question, just about that then. Though not before searching this site. If asking, please mention what data access libraries you are using.

Comment: In addition, if you use a single stored procedure, you can wrap it all in a transaction and make the whole thing atomic.  Granted, this can be done using a `Transaction` in ADO.NET as well.