# Join query between 2 tables, the first with several fields refering to the same fields in the other

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys

I have to build an application on an existing SQL database and I came upon this situation.

There's a table (call it `T1`) where several fields reference values from another table (`T2`), which basically is made up of just 2 fields, `Id` and `Name`. As a consequence, `T2` holds data of different nature and meaning, because the fields in `T1` that relate to it are of very different kinds. (This seems to me an unusual design.)

My question: given this design, how I can build a join query in order to get the value of `T2.Name` related to each `T1` field.

**EDIT**

I could get what I want by doing one query per field:

```
SELECT t2.name AS name1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.field1 = t2.id;

SELECT t2.name AS name2
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.field2 = t2.id;

SELECT t2.name AS name3
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.field3 = t2.id;
```

But this is nonsense. So how could I pack all this in one single query?

Comment: For each foreign key list t2 again giving it different alias.

Comment: Would [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12076322/1514813) not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29) references to t2 to get corresponding names:

```
SELECT alias1.name AS name1,
       alias2.name AS name2,
       alias3.name AS name3
  FROM t1
 INNER JOIN t2 alias1
    ON t1.field1 = alias1.id
 INNER JOIN t2 alias2
    ON t1.field2 = alias2.id
 INNER JOIN t2 alias3
    ON t1.field3 = alias3.id;
```

You might want to replace inner with left joins if foreign keys are nullable.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the table structures, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.col1, 
    t1.col2, 
    t1.id as t1_id, 
    t2.id as t2_id, 
    t2.name as t2_name
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Since you are joining the tables, you will just give a different alias for the columns that appear in both tables.

Based on your update, you should be able to consolidate those 3 queries into one:

```
SELECT t2.name AS name1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.id
    OR t1.field2 = t2.id
    OR t1.field3 = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use ORs in your join? So:

```
SELECT t2.name AS name3
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.field1 = t2.id
OR t1.field2 = t2.id
OR t1.field3 = t2.id;
```

If for some reason you cant then you can use `UNION` to combine the result of all the queries in a single query. I don't know which RDBMS your using but for postgres you can find information here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html

For any other a quick google of the DBMS name and "UNION" should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,

> SELECT t2.name AS name1,
>   
> (case when t1.field1 = t2.id then 'Type1' when t1.field2=t2.id then 'Type2' else 'Type3' end) as Type 
> FROM t1  
> INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.id 
> or
>   t1.field2=t2.id 
> or t1.field3=t2.id